# no guarda la información en la base Hibernate, jsf, primefaces, netbeans, apache tomcat

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate, primefaces, tomcat

Hola soy nuevo en la programación con **hibernate java primefaces jsf netbeans tomcat**, tengo el siguiente inconveniente al momento de guardar la información de la factura, no ejecuta ninguna función y no despliega ningún *error* en el *log*, mas si al inicial izar el sistema, esperando me sepan disculpar mi ignorancia y mil gracias por su ayuda.

Mi log:

> ````
> ene 06, 2020 12:06:08 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
>     GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/SysColor] registrÃ³ el conductor JDBC [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] pero fallÃ³ al anular el registro mientras la aplicaciÃ³n web estaba parada. Para prevenir un fallo de memoria, se ha anulado el registro del conductor JDBC por la fuerza.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:06:08 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>     GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/SysColor] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado [pool-18-thread-1] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:06:08 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>     GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/SysColor] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado [http-apr-8080-exec-108] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:06:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: Repliegue (undeploy) de la aplicaciÃ³n web que tiene como trayectoria de contexto /SysColor
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: Desplieque del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\SysColor.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:09 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para el contexto '/SysColor'
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:09 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: JSF1048: hay presentes anotaciones PostConstruct/PreDestroy.  Los mÃ©todos de beans administrados marcados con estas anotaciones procesarÃ¡n dichas anotaciones.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:14 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\SysColor.xml has finished in 8.172 ms
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:14 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
>     INFORMACIÃ“N: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SysColor]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
>     INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>     INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
>     INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
>     INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
>     INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
>     INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
>     WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>     INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sys/model/Factura.hbm.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>     INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sys/model/Vendedor.hbm.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>     INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sys/model/Cliente.hbm.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>     INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sys/model/Producto.hbm.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>     INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sys/model/Detallefactura.hbm.xml
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
>     INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>     WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>     INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facturacion?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>     INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>     INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>     INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:32 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
>     INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:32 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
>     INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
>     ene 06, 2020 12:07:32 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
>     INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory```
> ````

mapping:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Espero me puedan ayudar de verdad!!

Comment: Por favor añade tu código, para se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: ya lo publique mi estimado compañero

Answer (score 0):

dao

```
package sys.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import sys.model.Factura;

public interface facturaDao {

    //obtener ultimo registro de la tabla factura
    public Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro(Session session)throws Exception;

    //Averiguar si la tabla factura posee registros 
    public Long obtenerTotalRegistrosEnFactura(Session session);

    //Metodo para guardar el registro en la tabla factura
    public boolean guardaVentaFactura(Session session, Factura factura)throws Exception;

}
```

bean

```
    //Metodo para guardar la venta
    public void guardarVenta() {
        this.session = null;
        this.transaction = null;
          this.vendedor.setCodVendedor(2);
        try {
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            productoDao pDao = new productoDaoImp();
            facturaDao fDao = new facturaDaoImp();
            detalleFacturaDao dFDa = new detalleFacturaDaoImp();

            this.transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();

            //datos para guardar en la tabla factura de la BD
            this.factura.setNumeroFactura(this.numeroFactura.intValue());
            this.factura.setCliente(this.cliente);
            this.factura.setVendedor(this.vendedor);

            //Hacemos el insert en la tabla factura de la Bd
            fDao.guardaVentaFactura(this.session, this.factura);

            //Recuperar el ultimo registro de la factura
            this.factura = fDao.obtenerUltimoRegistro(this.session);

            //Recorremos el arralist  para guardar  cada registro en la BD
            for (Detallefactura item : listaDetalleFactura) {
                this.producto = pDao.obtenerProductoPorCodBarra(this.session, item.getCodBarra());
                item.setFactura(this.factura);
                item.setProducto(this.producto);

                //Insert en la tabla factura de la bd
                dFDa.guardaVentaDetalleFactura(this.session, item);

            }

            this.transaction.commit();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Correcto", "Factura Registrada"));

            this.limpiarFactura();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            if (this.transaction!=null) {
                this.transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if (this.session!=null) {
                this.session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Vista

```
<p:commandButton value="Registar" actionListener="#{facturaBean.guardarVenta()}"
                                         style="width: 150px; height: 60px;" update=":formFactura"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Imprimir" style="width: 150px; height: 60px;"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="#{facturaBean.limpiarFactura()}"
                                         style="width: 150px; height: 60px;"
                                         update=":formFactura"/>
```